# Proving similarity of matrices using characteristic polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $\ A $ be a real matrix of $\ 3 \times 3 $ with the characteristic polynom: $\ p(t) = t^3 + 2t^2 -3t $

Prove: the matrix $\ A^2 + A - 2I $ is similar to $\ D = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 &4 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & - 2 \end{bmatrix} $

$\ p(t) = t^3 +2t^2 -3t = t(t^2 + 2t -3) = t(t-1)(t+3) $ then $\ A $ has 3 eigenvalues $\ 0,1,-3 $ and is similar to $\ M =  \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 \\ 0 & -3 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & 0  \end{bmatrix}$

also,  $\ A^2 + A -2I = (A + 2I)(A-I) $

I can see that if I place $\ M$ instead so $\ (M+2I)(M-I) = D$ yet this is far from proving.

Comment: Try to prove that the relationship of similarity is maintained by polynomials, that is, if $A\sim D$ then also $p(A)\sim p(D).$ Do you see how this helps? :)

Comment: I did try to see it through the polynomials. the characteristic polynom of $\ p(D) = t(t-4)(t+2) $ yet If i'm not wrong, even same characteristic polynomials doesn't guarantee similarity and anyway I need to find the polynom of the matrix $\ A^2 + A - 2I $ which is different than $\ A $ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have almost finished.

It’s just necessary to prove that if $A\sim M$ then also $q(A)\sim q(M),$ where q(x) is a polynomial: using this with the polynomial $q(x)=x^2+x-2$ you can conclude.

So, let’s prove the property. By hypothesis there exists an invertibile Matrix $N$ such that $A=NMN^{-1}.$ Thanks to this you can say that $A^n=NMN^{-1}\cdots NMN^{-1}$ (n times), which is nothing but $NM^nN^{-1},$ (because the $N^{-1}$ and the $N$ in the middle eliminate each other) so the property is proven for monomials.

Passing from monomials to general polynomials is simple, due to the facts that you only have to group the polynomial between $N$ and $N^{-1}.$

Comment: Tell me if there is something unclear!

Comment: Thanks Riccardo! yet i'm having hard time to understand this . I understand that instead of $\ A^2 $ you chose $\ NM^2N^{-1}$ yet I still don't understand how did you jump to the conclusion that $\ NM^2N^{-1} + NMN^{-1} -2I $ is similar to the matrix $\ D $

Comment: 1st point) As you have written, the matrix $D$ is exactly $q(M)$ where $q(x)$ is the polynomial $x^2+x-2.$ At the same time, you have that $A$ is similar to $M$ so by the property that I proved $A^2+A-2I=q(A)$ is similar to $q(M)=D,$ which leads to the thesis. 2nd point) how to jump to conclusion: as I proved before, if $A$ is similar to $M,$ i.e. $A=NMN^{-1},$ then also $A^n$ is similar to $M^n$ by the same matrix $N$. This leads to conclusion because $A^2+A-2I= NM^2N^{-1}+NMN^{-1}-2I= N(M^2+M-2I)N^{-1}=NDN^{-1},$ which by definition means that $D$ is similar to $A^2+A-2I.$

Comment: Thanks for your patience Riccardo.. just how did you get to the polynomial $\ x^2 +x -2 $ ?? It is not the characteristic polynomial of $\ A \ D \ M $ ?

Comment: No, but it is the polynomial which evaluated in the matrix $A$ has to be proven to be similar to $D,$ and this is the reason why I used it.

Comment: But the polynomial characteristic of $\ A$ is $\ t^3 +2t -3 $ ... ?

Comment: Yes, but honestly why are you so concerned about using the characteristic polynomial? :) I mean, you can put a matrix in every polynomial you want, which corresponds exactly to what the problems wants you to do. So what I recommend you is to focus on what is the thesis of the problem, and retry to follow my procedure.

Comment: I don't care about the polynomial I just can't seem to understand where does it come from? Both answers just pop this polynomial $\ x^2 + x -2 $ out of nowhere and assume I understand it..

Comment: Because the thesis requires to prove that $A^2+A-2I$ is similar to $D$! And $A^2+A-2I$ is nothing but the polynomial $x^2+x-2$ evaluated in the matrix $A$. Sorry, I thought you had understood it because you also used it in the question (with the only difference that you had factorized it, which is the same).

Comment: Now I see ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

If $\lambda $ is an eigenvalue of $A$, and $q$ is a polynomial,  then $q(\lambda) $ is an e-value of $q(A)$.

Let $q(x)=x^2+x-2$.  You noted the e-values of $A$ are $1,-3$ and $0$.  Then $q(1)=0, q(-3)=4$ and $q(0)=-2$.

Now $q(A)$ is similar to..?  (Note that $q(A)$ is diagonalizable.)

Alternatively,  $q(M)=D$ (and q(A) is similar to $q(M)$; 
easy to prove).

Comment: Do you mean that $\ p(x) = x^2 + x -2 $ is the polynom of matrix $\ A^2+A-2I $ ?

Comment: I mean that $p(A)=A^2+A-2I$...